# Unable to install an azure app service site extension via PowerShell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am attempting to install an Azure web app site extension called Signal Sciences via a PowerShell script. The issue that I am having is that it doesn't seem to be finding the extension and so the installation is failing. I have tried using both the extension name "Signal Sciences WAF" and the ID "SignalSciences.Azure.Site.The extension"  Here is the command and the failure message is below.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
New-AzResource  -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/sites/siteextensions" -ResourceGroupName ResourceGroup -ResourceName "WEBAPP/Siteextensions/SignalSciences.Azure.Site.Extension)" -Force
```

```
New-AzResource : {"id":"/subscriptions/SUBiD/resourceGroups/ResourceGroup /providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/WEBAPP/siteextensions/Siteextensions","name":"hpfsweb-dev/Siteextensions","type":"Microsoft.Web/sites/sitee
xtensions","location":"South Central US","properties":{"id":"Siteextensions","title": null, "type":"Gallery","summary":null,"description":null,"version":null,"extension_url":null,"project_url":null,"icon_url":null,"license_url":null,"feed_url":null,"autho
rs":null,"installer_command_line_params":null,"published_date_time":null,"download_count":0,"local_is_latest_version":null,"local_path":null,"installed_date_time":null,"provisioningState":"Failed","comment":"'Siteextensions' not
found.","packageUri": null}}
```

I have tried the az command as well and it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install an extension to my Azure Webapp via `Az CLI` and was successful as follows.

While providing the `SignalSciences.Azure.Site.Extension` to the equivalent `CLI` command, you need to append the
`--properties '{}'`parameter.

```bash
az resource create --resource-group <ResourceGroup> --resource-type 'Microsoft.Web/sites/siteextensions' --name 'BlazorAppMSGraph/siteextensions/SignalSciences.Azure.Site.Extension' --api-version '2018-02-01' --properties '{}'
```

***Output:***

[image]

***Extension added to the given webapp successfully.***

[image]